# Running external program with multiple arguments in CMAKE

Tags: windows, cmake

Good Day...

I'm writing an app that requires cross compilation and runs and external command to convert images.

In linux and osx, the following works well:

```
EXECUTE_PROCESS( COMMAND convert ${PNG_FILE} -resize ${size}x${size} ${XPM_FILE})
```

However when I try to run it under windows, I receive the error "Invalid Paramer - -resize"

Any suggestions would be most appreciated...

Rob

Comment: Have you tried to execute your command by hand on the command? Are you sure PNG_FILE is not empty? Does it have a file extension?

Comment: Just a thought: `convert` is a command that comes with Windows (`> help convert` -> `Converts a FAT volume to NTFS. CONVERT volume /FS:NTFS [/V] [/CvtArea:filename] [/NoSecurity] [/X]`. So give a full path to ImageMagick's `convert.exe` program. CMake can help you finding it: use [`include(FindImageMagick)`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/module/FindImageMagick.html) and `find_package(ImageMagick COMPONENTS convert)`. Then `EXECUTE_PROCESS( COMMAND ${ImageMagick_EXECUTABLE_DIR}/convert.exe ${PNG_FILE} -resize ${size}x${size} ${XPM_FILE})`.

Comment: That did it, Florian... Many thanks!

Comment: @BassCleff66 You're welcome. I've turned my comment into an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since [`execute_command()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.4/command/execute_process.html) does use the OS shell you/CMake probably found Window's own `convert.exe`:

```
 > help convert 
 Converts a FAT volume to NTFS. 
 CONVERT volume /FS:NTFS [/V] [/CvtArea:filename] [/NoSecurity] [/X]
```

So give a full path to ImageMagick's [`convert.exe`](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/convert.php) program. CMake can [help you finding it](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.4/module/FindImageMagick.html):

```
include(FindImageMagick) 
find_package(ImageMagick COMPONENTS convert REQUIRED)
EXECUTE_PROCESS( COMMAND ${ImageMagick_EXECUTABLE_DIR}/convert ${PNG_FILE} -resize ${size}x${size} ${XPM_FILE})
```